# DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response (resuelto)

Tags: php, json, datatables

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde realizo una consulta.

```
include_once 'conexion.php';

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM herramientas";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$resultado) {
    die("Error");
} else {
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        $arreglo["data"][] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Pensaba que me tiraba un error por los acentos pero no es asi. Me tira el siguiente error `DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response`. Pero si realizo a otra tabla me funciona bien. Debera ser por los formatos o contenido de los campos?

```
var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({

                "destroy": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "include/JSON.php"
                },
                "order": [
               [0, "desc"]
           ],
                "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "Codigo"
                },  {
                    "data": "Estado"
                },  {
                    "data": "Descripcion"
                }],

                "language": idioma_espanol
            });
```

Ya le agrege `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

**Solución**

```
$tabla = "";

if (!$resultado) {
    die("Error");
} else {

    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        // $arreglo["data"][] = $data;
        $tabla.='{"Codigo":"'.$data['Codigo'].'","Estado":"'.$data['Estado'].'"},';
    }
    $tabla= substr($tabla,0,strlen($tabla)-1);
    echo '{"data":['.$tabla.']}';
    //echo json_encode($arreglo,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Comment: cuando mandas tu JSON desde PHP haciendole echo, debes pasarle este otro parámetro json_encode( $var, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ); el que dice JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Comment: no pongas **resuelto** en el titulo de tu pregunta, cuando hayas encontrado la respuesta adecuada marcala como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien el problema que tienes, si es que no quieres que los caracteres especiales se convierten en formato \u....

El receptor tiene que revertir la codificación, normalmente lo hace automáticamente, por ejemplo en php usando json_decode(data_json) lo convierte sin más.

Pero aun así quieres que no se conviertan, usa la opción JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Test

```
$response = "Técnologia";

echo json_encode($response); //T\u00e9cnologia
echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); //Técnologia
```

tambien puedes asegurar de que no te salga ningun caracter estraño haciendo lo siguiente:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

aqui teneis la documentacion [documentacion](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

Comment: ese header donde lo agrego?

Comment: antes del while

Comment: duda es la siguiente estoy realizando este JSON en mi localhost y funciona bien, pero cuando lo llevo al server que tiene version de php 5.6. me falla en algunas tablas